# auto-initialize Fields created by JCodeModel

Tags: java, jcodemodel

I create a new Java class through a Json, i.e. :

```
{
    "package" : "crud.vaadin",
    "className" : "StudentForm",
    "extension" : "AbstractForm",
    "extensiongeneric" : "Person",
    "properties" : {
        "Name" : {
            "type" : "MTextField"
        },
        "Email" : {
            "type" : "MTextField"
        }
    },
    "model" : "Person"
}
```

will generate :

```
package crud.vaadin;

public class StudentForm extends AbstractForm<Person>
    {

        private MTextField Email;
        private MTextField Name;

    }
```

I use JCodeModel for the StudentForm generation and the Field generating method looks like this:

```
    public void createFields(Map<String, Object> properties, JDefinedClass jc, JCodeModel model) {
            for(String key : properties.keySet()){
            //getType returns MTextField and key is either Email or Name
                String type = getType(prop.get(key));
                String name = key;
                try {
                    JType jt = model.parseType(type);
                    JFieldVar field = jc.field(JMod.PRIVATE, jt, name);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

But I would like to initialize the fields upon creation of the source.

```
private MTextField email = new MTextField("Email");
```

Is there a way to extend the JFieldVar by the initialization?

Comment: SOLVED! `jc.field(JMod.PRIVATE, jt, name, JExpr._new(jt).arg(name));` is the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to specify an initializing `JExpression` with the `.field` call like so:

```
JFieldVar field = jc.field(JMod.PRIVATE, jt, name, JExpr._new(jt).arg(name));
```